# Passing an NSMutableArray to a DetailView from UITableViewController - iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController which presents another UITableViewController when a cell is tapped. I have an NSMutableArray which I want to pass into the new UITableViewController when instantiated.

I would usually do something like :

```
- (void)loadStationList {

 StationListView * listView = [[StationListView alloc] initWithNibName:@"StationListView" bundle:nil];
 listView.dataList = newParser.stationData;
 // ...
 // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
 NSLog(@"New Parser is %d", [newParser.stationData count]); //This is fine - all objects in array here.
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:listView animated:NO];
```

}

The odd thing is that dataList (the NSMutableArray pointer in the new class) is empty (I am in checking in the number of rows delegate method).

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of rows in the section.
NSLog(@"Data List is %d", [dataList count]);
return [dataList count];

}
```

I have tried several different approaches (such as instantiating a new NSMutable array in the parent class) however nothing seems to work. This may be ARC related as I am still relatively new to ARC. Can anyone help ?

Comment: How did you declare the dataList property? Also, in `- tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`, are you accessing the instance variable directly or is your code `self.dataList`?

Comment: Declared as strong : @property (strong) NSMutableArray * dataList; and then synthensized. I am using dataList.count - adding self.dataList or not does not make any difference.

Comment: In place of `NSLog(@"New Parser is %d", [newParser.stationData count]);`, have you tried `NSLog(@"List View dataList is %d", [listView.dataList count]);` (before pushing the view controller)? If the count is correct, you might be inadvertently manipulating `dataList` in the `StationListView`.

Comment: Ok that's odd - you are right - it returns the correct count at that point. But I can't see that I'm manipulating it anywhere after. Maybe its being dealloced somehow... ?

Comment: I admit I am also relatively new to ARC, but I don't think it is being deallocated. I think it should have thrown an exception if that happened. Could you satisfy the persistent me and try `[self.dataList count]` instead in the `- tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` method? :)

Comment: NSLog(@"Data List is %d", [self.dataList count]); still returns 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I got round this by created an instance variable in the app delegate and then saving and reading the array from there. This does look like a bug in arc - it works with other variable types.

Comment: I do not think its an ARC problem - still. As asked before, how did you define your dataList in the first place? wasn't dataList always an iVar in your StationListView ?  I am a little confused...

Answer (score 0):

How did you declare `dataList`,`newParser.stationData` ?
Should be sth like this

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray       *dataList;
```

Anyway, to ensure that you do not loose any values, you may want to copy/assign each element from `newParser.stationData` to `dataList`.
Like here:

```
    NSMutableArray * dataList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (id arrayElement in newParser.stationData) {
        [dataList addObject:arrayElement];
            }
```

Try this instead of the simple assignment `listView.dataList = newParser.stationData;`. ps don't worry about efficieny this is so fast it will not matter.

Comment: Still no luck. I'm beginning to think this is a bug in arc.